# Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit message during rails installation on window 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails

**i am getting error when i am exe command gem install rails**

```
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.


C:/Ruby193/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=C:/Ruby193/bin/ruby
        --with-atomic_reference-dir
        --without-atomic_reference-dir
        --with-atomic_reference-include
        --without-atomic_reference-include=${atomic_reference-dir}/include
        --with-atomic_reference-lib
        --without-atomic_reference-lib=${atomic_reference-dir}/lib
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:381:in `try_do': The compiler failed to genera
te an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:461:in `try_link0'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:712:in `try_run'
        from extconf.rb:26:in `<main>'

Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/atomic-1.
1.14 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/atomic-1.1.14/ext/gem_make
.out
```

Comment: yes there is log file

Comment: Seriously, don't try to use Ruby on Windows, you'll run into lots of troubles. Use Vagrant to set up a Linux virtual machine.

Comment: i want to run ruby on window 7 64 bit system

Comment: yes there is log file with lot of description but not understandable how to fix

Comment: @KhanMuhammad, is your issue fixed?

Answer (score 2):

You should follow these instructions;

-DevKit is located at C:\Ruby\DevKit

- c:\Ruby\DevKit>ruby dk.rb (in the command prompt)
- c:\Ruby\DevKit>ruby dk.rb init

-c:\Ruby\DevKit>ruby dk.rb review

-c:\Ruby\DevKit>ruby dk.rb install

It must work after them.

More info : http://rubyonwindowsguides.github.io/book/ch02-04.html

Answer (score 1):

on  window 7 64  bit system
1) if you want to work with ruby version lesst then ruby 2.0
2) you need to install DevKit  32 bit from  http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/  on window 7 x64 bit

if you want to install ruby 2 or greater version on window 7 64 so you need to install  DevKit  64 bit  with  ruby 2 with 64 bit

with DevKit 64 bit on window 7  64 bit system ruby 32 bit will not work

but window 7 64 bit system with Devkit 32 bit and ruby 32 bit will work

this issue will not come

Answer (score 1):

For 64 Environment, make sure Ruby and DevKit are 64. Then Exact DevKit in separate Folder. Follow above comEngineer process, make sure config.yml has correct path of ruby. - C:/Ruby23-x64

Try msys.bat in side DevKit extraction location instead of command prompt,
Then run gem install rails

if it not working, Please run devkitvar.ps1 File and re try above step agian